# Inscrutable Error

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am getting this error in my sinatra app:

```
NameError at / uninitialized constant Category file: app.rb location: block in <top (required)> line: 8
```

app.rb

```
get('/') do
  @recipes = Recipe.all
  @categories = Category.all
  erb(:index)
end
```

index.erb

```
<% if @categories.any?() %>
    <% @categories.each() do |category| %>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='/category/<%=category.id()%>'> <%=category.cat_name()%></a></li>
        </ul>
    <%end%>
<%else %>
  <p> You have no categories!</p>
<%end%>
```

It fails at: `@categories = Category.all`  in app.rb

It also fails with the same error in rspec:

```
require('spec_helper')
describe(Category) do

    it('creates a new category') do
        category = Catergory.create({:cat_name => 'italian'})
        expect(category.cat_name()).to(eq(category.cat_name))
    end
end
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:recipes)
end
```

Recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:ingredients)
  has_many(:instructions)
  has_many(:images)
  belongs_to(:category)
end
```

Comment: How is `Recipe` being loaded? Are you doing the same for `Category`? Is it possible there's a typo in your `Category` class definition?

Comment: Per my previous comment, there is a typo in your test: `Catergory.create`.

Comment: You are right! I corrected it and the test passes.  But no typos in my class that I can see.  I will include it above.

Comment: the app is working now. I'm new to stackoverflow. How do I mark this as the best answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why the typo in your test would have been affecting the controller, but maybe that exception was the result of running it? Anyways, I'll submit a proper answer, which you can then accept. :)

Comment: You hit the checkmark next to the answer to accept it

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your test.

Change `Catergory` to `Category` in:

```
category = Catergory.create({:cat_name => 'italian'})
```